# Microservices Deployment Strategy using Opensource Platform

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

Hi I am new to microservices architect and have few questions related to its deployment on production environment.
I am using spring boot microservices and want to deploy them on any open source plantform like kubernetes.
Previously I have all deployments on local servers(conventional hardware). So I don't want to move to any cloud service for now, its part of future planing. I want to have a deployment strategy that should work with servers and in future when I want to move to cloud, effort should be minimum. I need some expert suggestions. I have created a POC of deploying apps to kubernetes with minikube where I am using docker container. But for docker private repositories I need to buy their enterprise services. 
And for any cloud platform I also need invest money.

What are the other choices where I can deploy microservices on my conventional hardware.

Caas vs PaaS, CF vs K8s
[image]

Comment: What are you actually asking? Are you asking for alternatives to Kubernetes?

Comment: What are the other choices where I can deploy microservices on my conventional hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Two ways of doing it. Actually three, the third being not moving to cloud. If moving to cloud, you do it either via `OCF` or via `Docker`. for `OCF`, we have lot of providers including `Pivotal`. For `Docker`, you go via `Kubernetes`. Again there are a lot of providers, `AKS`, `PKS`, `GCP`, etc. 
The choice is always yours.